# ERROR: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present WordPress

Tags: wordpress, cloudflare, mautic

I am working on a wordpress website and I have installed mautic plugin into the website. Now issue is that I am getting the following error in the console. Cloud flare is also enabled.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mautic.my-domain.com/mtc/event' from origin 'https://www.my-domain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have tried different solutions for the issue but never get rid of this error.
I have tried by removing the trailing slash (/) from the domain name.
I have also used the " **Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin 'https://www.my-domain.com'** "

I have read many threads here at stack overflow, github and mautic forum but Still looking for the solution. Please help in this regard and thank you in advance

Comment: Do you use apache webserver? Do you have access to configurations?

Comment: Yes I'm using apache webserver. what type of configurations???

Answer (score 1):

In Mautic
`Configurations > System Settings > CORS Settings`
either set it to NO in order to not restrict domains,
or set it to YES and Add domain you want to allow.
[image]

Comment: Also, make sure the domain does NOT include a trailing slash when entering it into the Mautic settings if you turn Restrict Domains to YES. This was the solution for the error I received on my site.